# Distribution of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability

We consider the following random variable $X$: We have a uniform distribution of the numbers of the unit interval $[0,1]$. After a number $x$ from $[0,1]$ is chosen, numbers from $[0,1]$ are chosen until a number $y$ with $x\leq y$ pops up.

The random variable $X$ counts the number of trials to obtain $y$. How to calculate $P(X=n)$, $n=1,2,\ldots$?

Comment: Were any of these answers helpful in solving your problem? If so, you should accept one of them by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is naturally of independent draws of numbers.

Given $x\in[0,1]$, the probability that $y<x$ is just $x$, so the probability that $n-1$ numbers were chosen and all smaller than $x$ is $x^{n-1}$, and you want the next number to be at least $x$, so the probability for that is $(1-x)$. Thus:

$$P(X=n)=x^{n-1}(1-x),$$

if the initial $x$ is fixed, non-random, and

$$P(X=n)=\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)\,dx=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1},$$

if the sample space of $X$ includes random choices of the initial $x$, and then the distribution of $X$ is of course independent of $x$.

As written, and in lack of any additional information, the original question may be interpreted in both ways.

Comment: But then you have to integrate that against the initial distribution of $x$.

Comment: @Ian I don't understand your comment. I have just computed the distribution of $X$, which is what the question asks for.

Comment: "After a number $x$ from $[0,1]$ is chosen", in context it sounds like $x$ is also chosen randomly according to the same distribution as $y$.

Comment: So for that we would simply use $P(X=n)=\int_x P(X=n| x = x) P(x) = 1/n - 1/(n + 1)$?

Comment: I agree with @Ian. I think that $x$ is a meant to be a random variable here.

Comment: @drhab But the answer has still has a positive voting (in total). The voting system on MSE is really informative.

Comment: @callculus In situations like this I tend to wait with downvoting. This to give the answerer the opportunity to defend/repair/delete. If tomorrow things are unchanged then I will consider downvoting. What do you think in this matter? Is $x$ random or not?

Answer (score 2):

The event $X=n$ occurs if and only if among the first $n$ draws of the uniform random variable, $U_1,U_2,\dots,U_n$, that $U_n$ is the largest and $U_1$ is the second largest. Assuming $n\ge 2$ (which is true if you want $P(X=n)>0$), then the probability of this is easily seen to be $$\frac{1}n\times \frac{1}{n-1}.$$
This is because the $n!$ possibile orderings of $U_1,U_2,\dots,U_n$ are equally likely, and in $\frac1n$ of these orderings $U_n$ is the largest, and in $\frac1{n-1}$ of the orderings where $U_n$ is the largest $U_1$ is the second largest.

Comment: +1 This solution is more elegant than mine.

Comment: Thanks for this very elegant solution, and sorry for my very late comment!

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ denote the number chosen uniformly from $[0,1]$.

Then $P(X=n\mid U=u)=u^{n-1}(1-u)$ and $f_U(u)=1_{[0,1]}$ so that:$$P(X=n)=\int_0^1P(X=n\mid U=u)du=\left[\frac{u^{n}}{n}-\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Here $X$ counts the number of trials needed to get a number that exceeds $U$ and the $U$ is **not** looked at as one of these trials.

Comment: An equally valid interpretation of the question is that the distribution of $X$ is dependent on $x$, that is, the conditionality is non-random.

Comment: @uniquesolution Then why is $x$ a **chosen** number in this context? If that is not relevant then it is merely confusing and can be left out.

Comment: The word **chosen** in the context may have an isomorphic meaning to that of the word **specified**. It is a small matter indeed, of not much significance, but if you want to stress that a point is **random** you ought to marry that word to the chosen one.

Comment: @uniquesolution The OP might clarify this matter. Let's just wait and see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and please excuse my very late comment!